# How to write multiple IF statements in 1 cell based on multiple dropdown choices?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

`L16-L19` are `Yes/NO` dropdowns

How can I use multiple IF statements in `L20`?

For example:

```
yes yes yes no, “proceed”

No no yes yes, “don't proceed”

Yes no yes yes, “cannot move forward”
```

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IFS` formula

```
=IFERROR(IFS(AND(L16="Y",L17="Y",L18="Y",L19="N"),"proceed",
             AND(L16="N",L17="N",L18="Y",L19="Y"),"don't proceed",
             AND(L16="Y",L17="N",L18="Y",L19="Y"),"cannot move forward"),"NOW ???")
```

[image]

Further reading:

- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [`AND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)